# Angular 4 routing with nested module and wildcards

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an Angular 4 app with a very simple routing because I'm creating the routes dynamically; so these are my routes in my app.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'home'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageComponent,
    resolve: {
      content: PageResolve
    }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    AuthModule
  ]
```

This is working fine.
I'm now adding authentication in a separated module, so I got an auth.module.ts with this:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' },
      { path: 'login',  component: 'LoginComponent' },
      { path: 'register', componente: 'RegisterComponent' }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)]
})
```

The problem now (I think) is that when I access `localhost:4200/home` the app works fine, but if I access `localhost:4200/auth` instead of redirecting to LoginComponent, the wildcard defined in main module matches the url and it goes to PageComponent instead.

I think I can import the routes from auth.module.ts in app.module.ts and use them like this:

```
{
  path: 'auth',
  children: AUTH_ROUTES
}
```

but I don´t want to do that, I'd like to keep those routes inside the auth.module only.

Is there a way I can make sure the wildcard routes are checked at the very end only?

Thanks

Comment: It needs to be imported into your app.module or the route isn't registered.

Comment: please post @NgModule({... from the first app.module.

Comment: yes, they are already imported

Comment: @David, reversing the order of modules loading the wildcard will be loaded after those in authmodule. So suggest you to reverse the order AuthModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes) in the imports.

Comment: that's correct, I can mark it as the right answer if you write it